# Domínio redirecionando para dominio com ssl

Tags: ssl

Estou enfrentando um problema, temos um domínio principal que está com o *SSL* instalado e temos uma variação deste domínio, que eu eu registrei para auxiliar na hora de procurarem pelo site na internet.

Usamos `nginx`, em um `droplet` da Digital Ocean.

Fiz o apontamento pela digital ocean, e funciona ok, ao digitar o endereço X ele entra no meu droplet, porém ele nao muda para o endereço Y (o que tem o *SSL*) e da erro de segurança, diz que o endereço X tem um certificado inválido.

Desculpem se ficou um pouco confuso, o que eu preciso fazer é, digitar o endereço X e ele redirecionar para o endereço Y.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar: https://christiaanconover.com/blog/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx, se conseguir não esqueça de postar a solução.. ;)

Comment: Então, não deu certo, porque quando eu digito o domínio X (http://x.com) ele entra em https://x.com e diz que não tem um certificado válido, ao invés de entrar em http://x.com e jogar pra https://y.com

Comment: Hum.. Vc tem algum certificado ssl para o domínio x.com? Pois vc tem que ter um certificado por domínio.

Comment: não, não temos, putz, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Se os dois domínios são SSL, cada um tem de ter seu certificado comprado em separado.

Answer (score -2):

Tentou fazer um redirect pelo .htaccess?

```
redirect 301 http://siteX.com.br https://siteY.com.br
```

E se quiser mudar o domínio inteiro, para não perder a força dos links que apontam para o site, ou visitante. Faça da seguinte forma:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) https://siteY.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```